# Deleting from Table with Entity Framework/ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to delete a whole row of data from a table. The code I'm using is:

```
OModel.Cart pncart = database.Carts.FirstOrDefault(
                        pn => pn.OrderId == Session["OOID"] && 
                        pn.PartNumber == Request.QueryString["PartNumber"]);

database.Carts.DeleteObject(pncart);
database.SaveChanges();
```

And the error it gives me, is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object
>   get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities
>   does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

It says something about `NotSupportException`, so I'm guessing you just can't do it this way.

So, how would I go about deleting from the table? I thought this was the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would declare variables for the `Session["OOID"]` and `Request.QueryString["PartNumber"]` instead of using them within your linq expression.

I believe it is telling you that it cannot translate those operations.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to Entities get's stuck on embedded expression (LINQ to SQL handles this better). You have to break the embedded expressions out, so that the lambda only contains string constants.

```
string ooid = Session["OOID"];
string partNo = Request.QueryString["PartNumber"];

OModel.Cart pncart = database.Carts.FirstOrDefault(
                        pn => pn.OrderId == ooid && pn.PartNumber == partNo);
```